# Adove Business Catalyst receiving uneven emails

Tags: business-catalyst

Here is [my website](http://www.tiffanycrosara.com/). I was receiving uneven emails for the last 2-3 days. I really don't know what's happening. Please suggest any ideas.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "uneven" in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [Captcha](https://www.google.bg/search?q=Captcha&oq=Captcha&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.222j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to your form.

That would prevent bots from submitting queries on your website

See [this guide](https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/user-manual/CRM/CAPTCHA/adding-captcha-to-forms) and [this one](https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/user-manual/CRM/CAPTCHA/replacing-captcha-with-recaptcha) on the BC website